# SQL Server query XML xpath empty namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I encountered a strange behavior on SQL Server 2008 R2 when performing a Xpath query on a XML field with nodes which have an empty namespace.

This query doesn't return results:

```
[xml_field].query('/RootNode/NodeWithEmptyNamespace')
```

This query returns results:

```
[xml_field].query('/dft:RootNode/NodeWithEmptyNamespace')
```

For clarification this query also returns results so no prefix is mandatory for root node (and probably default namespace):

```
[xml_field].query('/RootNode')
```

According to the [XML namespace default documation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) when empty namespace is defined the namespace is none.

The XML in the database is the following:

```
<RootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
  <otherNode>Dummy data</otherNode>
  <NodeWithEmptyNamespace xmlns="">Other dummy data</NodeWithEmptyNamespace>
</RootNode>
```

The full query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://tempuri.org' as dft)
SELECT TOP 150 [ID],
       [xml_field].query('/dft:RootNode/NodeWithEmptyNamespace')
  FROM [database];
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior or is this a bug?

Comment: The `<RootNode>` has a non-empty XML namespace - so you have to define and use it - I don't understand what your question really is .....

Comment: My question is not clear, both /RootNode and /dft:RootNode return the RootNode, so the prefix is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what your problem is. With the XML sample you have posted the `RootNode` element and the `otherNode` element are in the namespace `http://tempuri.org` while the `NodeWithEmptyNamespace` element is in no namespace (as the `xmlns=""` puts it there). With XPath a path or step `NodeWithEmptyNamespace` selects elements of that name in no namespace and `RootNode` would select an element of that name in **no** namespace too, only in your input there is no such element. So your path `/dft:RootNode/NodeWithEmptyNamespace` is doing the right thing, it selects the element with local name `RootNode` in the namespace tied to the `dft` prefix (i.e. `http://tempuri.org`) and its child element with local name `NodeWithEmptyNamespace` in no namespace.

Comment: I made the confusion that an empty default namespace was the same of no namespace declaration, in other words that <a xmlns=""/> was equal to <a>. In the first case (contrary to what I thought) there is no namespace of the node <a> and the second case the namespace is the same of the parent node.